# Trigonometric Integrals: $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin^2(x) \cos^2(x) \,dx$

Tags: calculus

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin^2(x) \cos^2(x) \, dx$$

I have two questions:

1) I used the half identity formulas but got no where (see attachment). 
Can someone guide me how to solve this problem utilizing this identity.

2) My solutions manual is using this identity $\cos^2(x) \sin^2(x)=\dfrac{1-\cos(4x)}{8}$

How did they get that?

[image]

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{4}[1-\cos(2x)][1+\cos(2x)]=\frac{1}{4}[1-\cos^2(2x)]$$
$$=\frac{1}{4}[1-\frac{1+\cos 4x}{2}]=\frac{1-\cos 4x}{8}$$

Comment: I am little confused as to how $1-cos^2(2x)$ becomes $\frac{1}{2}(1+cos(4x))$ How does the angle 2x become 4x?

Comment: @Cetshwayo depending on the the half identity formulas

Comment: @Cetshwayo $\cos^2 2x=\frac{1+\cos 4x}{2}$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Since $\sin(2x)=2\sin x\cos x$ we have $$(\sin x\cos x)^2=\left(\frac{1}{2}\sin (2x)\right)^2=\frac{1}{4}\sin^2 (2x)$$
On the other hand, the identity $\cos (2t)=1-\sin^2 t$ implies $\sin^2t=\frac{1-\cos (2t)}{2}$
Then, $$(\sin x\cos x)^2=\frac{1}{4}\sin^2 (2x)=\frac{1}{8}(1-\cos 4x)$$

Comment: This is the approach that I would have taken.  +1

Answer (score 1):

Notice, we know from $\gamma$ function $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^m\theta\cos^n \theta\ d\theta=\frac{\Gamma{\left(\frac{m+1}{2}\right)}\Gamma{\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}}{2\Gamma{\left(\frac{m+n+2}{2}\right)}}$$
& $\Gamma{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}=\sqrt{\pi}$

Hence, we get $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^2(x)\cos^2 (x)\ dx$$$$=\frac{\Gamma{\left(\frac{2+1}{2}\right)}\Gamma{\left(\frac{2+1}{2}\right)}}{2\Gamma{\left(\frac{2+2+2}{2}\right)}}$$ $$=\frac{\Gamma{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}\Gamma{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}}{2\Gamma{(3)}}$$
$$=\frac{\frac{1}{2}\Gamma{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}\frac{1}{2}\Gamma{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}}{2(2!)}$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\sqrt{\pi}}{16}=\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{16}}$$

Comment: A bit beyond the scope of the OP (I think) but +1 in any case.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{aligned}
& \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin ^{2} x \cos ^{2} x d x \\
=& \frac{1}{4} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin ^{2}(2 x) d x \\
=& \frac{1}{8} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(1-\cos 4 x) d x \\
=& \frac{1}{8}\left[x-\frac{\sin 4 x}{4}\right]_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \\
=& \frac{\pi}{16}
\end{aligned}